# Short story where a sideshow barker asks a child to debunk his paranormal exhibits, including ectoplasm

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

The question has most of the elements that I remember, but not the author or title of the short story, which I’ve forgotten.

The barker is setting up the exhibit and invites a child to critique it. As each audacious statement is made by the barker, the child shouts “lie!” to the false statements. “Ectoplasm” is one of – or the last of – the exhibits.

I probably read the short story pre-millennium in an anthology. It could have been a fantasy anthology.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read this in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: I probably read the short story pre-millennium in an anthology. It could have been a fantasy anthology. All of the relevant elements are stated. It was a straightforward interaction between the man who owned the exhibit and the clever child, pointing out for every item in the show how the man’s pitch was bogus flim-flam.